# FreeBSD: Can't load libphp5.so or read php files

Tags: freebsd, apache-httpd, php

I'm having a bit of a trouble configuring my apache server on freebsd.
I installed apache24, php5 and php5 extensions, moved my files over to ./data.
I made some changes to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache24/libphp5.so
<IfModule dir_module>
<IfModule php5_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
<IfModule !php5_module>
<IfModule php4_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
<IfModule !php4_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and to my php.conf:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
<IfModule php4_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
<IfModule php5_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The problem is, when I restart my apache24 service the following error appears:
[image]

Also, without the "LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache24/libphp5.so" it doesn't read php files, it simply shows the source.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [mod_php5](http://www.freshports.org/www/mod_php5):

```
pkg install mod_php5
```

Comment: Thank you! Im new to this unix thing, sorry about the newb doubt!

Comment: No problem :) You're welcome :)